# How to Run the App in iPad Simulator?

Tags: ipad, ios-simulator

I'm developing an application and I seem to have set something so it only runs in iPhone Simulator and not in iPad simulator (when I try to change the device in the Simulator from iPhone to iPad it simply opens it again in iPhone Simulator mode; in the iPad Sim the app doesn't show in the applications list).

How do I add the iPad run capability to my app?

Comment: version 3.2.3.
is that what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set

```
iPhone/iPad
```

in your project's build settings (Deployment: "Targeted Device Family").

Answer (score 0):

Select your target (i.e. not the target menu, but the target inside the menu.)
Click on the Project menu & choose "Upgrade Current Target for iPad."
In the dialog box that comes up, you're given two choices.  Select "One Universal Application."

And that should be it.  Previously, you had to roll back the deployment target for iOS to 3.2 since that was the latest version running on iPad.  You would do this by right-clicking on the target, selecting getInfo from the popup menu, and looking through the Build Tab of the popup window for the deployment target.  That should no longer be necessary as iPad now runs on iOS 4.3.  But, if you have not updated your Xcode, the iPad simulator may still run only on version 3.2 or earlier.

Hope this works for you.